# get data from page that a url points to

Tags: c#, asp.net

Given a Url, I'd like to be able to capture the Title of the page this url points to, as well
as other info - eg a snippet of text from the first paragraph on a page? - maybe even an image from the page.

Digg.com does this nicely when you submit a url.

How could something like this be done in .Net c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), which can parse malformed HTML documents.
You can use its `HTMLWeb` class to download a webpage over HTTP.

---

You can also download text over HTTP using .Net's [`WebClient` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx).
However, it won't help you parse the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

## You could try something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace WebGet
{
    class progMain
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ASCIIEncoding asc = new ASCIIEncoding();
            WebRequest wrq = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost");

            WebResponse wrp = wrq.GetResponse();
            byte [] responseBuf = new byte[wrp.ContentLength];

            int status = wrp.GetResponseStream().Read(responseBuf, 0, responseBuf.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(asc.GetString(responseBuf));
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have the buffer, you can process it looking for paragraph or image HTML tags to extract portions of the returned data.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the title of a page with a function like the following. You would need to modify the regular expression to look for, say, the first paragraph of text but since each page is different, that may prove difficult. You could look for a meta description tag and take the value from that, however.

```
public static string GetWebPageTitle(string url)
{
   // Create a request to the url
   HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

   // If the request wasn't an HTTP request (like a file), ignore it
   if (request == null) return null;

   // Use the user's credentials
   request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

   // Obtain a response from the server, if there was an error, return nothing
   HttpWebResponse response = null;
   try { response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse; }
   catch (WebException) { return null; }

   // Regular expression for an HTML title
   string regex = @"(?<=<title.*>)([\s\S]*)(?=</title>)";

   // If the correct HTML header exists for HTML text, continue
   if (new List<string>(response.Headers.AllKeys).Contains("Content-Type"))
      if (response.Headers["Content-Type"].StartsWith("text/html"))
      {
         // Download the page
         WebClient web = new WebClient();
         web.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
         string page = web.DownloadString(url);

         // Extract the title
         Regex ex = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
         return ex.Match(page).Value.Trim();
      }

   // Not a valid HTML page
   return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Selenium RC (Open Source, www.seleniumhq.org) to parse data etc. from the pages. It is a web test automation tool with an C# .Net lib.

Selenium have full API to read out specific items on a html page.